# How to disable data adapter in Ember.js to only use browser storage?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, storage

I'm building an application that only does CRUD operations on data directly in the browser so that the user can export it later as a JSON file.

I'm new to ember and read a bit about the store.

I tried to use it but everytime I try to save my data, the store is calling the adapter to save the data on the server (which I don't have)

Is it possible to disable that and only use the storage in the browser ?
Is there a cleaner way to do this ? What would that be ?

Any suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Customizing Adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-adapters/) guide, they refer the reader to a github repo of an adapter implementation for that purposes [local storage backend](https://github.com/locks/ember-localstorage-adapter)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the links. Do you have any recommendations on a better way of doing this ? Thanks